# How many queries to Laravel DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent, event-sourcing

I have a form request where I check for an existing user for instance `'email' => ['required', 'exists:users']`. I know a request is made to DB to check for an existing user right?

What happens when I need the user object elsewhere? Say, in a middleware? in a service class? and event listener/handler (without queues)? Are all of these new requests to the DB?

I am currently using the Spatie event-sourcing package and noticed a unique challenge. I need the user object in `Projectors` and other `Reactors`. The same event occurring can be handled by different projectors and different reactors for different business rules. Is a new request made to DB for the user object every time I do a `User::where*...` ?

Basically what I want to find out is, would it be a good idea, to get the user object once, store it as some global variable eg. `$GLOBALS['current_user'] = $user` and then always reference this instead of making new requests to DB? Possibly, unset it at the last point where I may need it?

Comment: For the first part: yes. `exists` will do one query, and if you do it elsewhere, it will do it again, and again, and again, there is no "intermediate" cache or similar by default. For the second part: never use `$GLOBALS` anymore... you can use other stuff like `singleton` or other bindings. So doing `User::where*` all the time will trigger a new query (when you call `get` or `pluck`, etc.). You can see this using [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and see all the queries.

Comment: This is one of the drawbacks of using the active records pattern. In general doing two queries that only fetch a single row is never gonna be a performance problem. So i would call this premature optimization. The biggest problem will be N + 1 queries.